# Empty XML split out default XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML passing to the XSL which gives the standard output. There is chance that i will get the XML as empty some times based on some cases. Is there any way if we have empty XML and get the standard or default out put in XSL ?

Comment: What do you mean by empty?  Would be be a 0 bytes or an empty root element?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way if we have empty XML
>   and get the standard or default out
>   put in XSL ?

**You can never have "empty XML".**

By definition, a well-formed XML document must have a top element. If an XSLT 1.0 transformation is being applied on any non-well-formed XML document, any compliant XSLT 1.0 processor must produce an error and no processing is done.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-doc-available

> If fn:doc($uri) returns a document
>   node, this function returns true. If
>   $uri is not a valid xs:anyURI, an
>   error is raised [err:FODC0005].
>   Otherwise, this function returns
>   false.

And from http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-doc

> One possible processing model for this
>   function is as follows. The resource
>   identified by the URI Reference is
>   retrieved. If the resource cannot be
>   retrieved, an error is raised
>   [err:FODC0002]. The data resulting
>   from the retrieval action is then
>   parsed as an XML document and a tree
>   is constructed in accordance with the
>   [XQuery 1.0 and XPath 2.0 Data Model].
>   If the top-level media type is known
>   and is "text", the content is parsed
>   in the same way as if the media type
>   were text/xml; otherwise, it is parsed
>   in the same way as if the media type
>   were application/xml. If the contents
>   cannot be parsed successfully, an
>   error is raised [err:FODC0002].
>   Otherwise, the result of the function
>   is the document node at the root of
>   the resulting tree. This tree is then
>   optionally validated against a schema.

So, it looks like you could do this (I'm being cautious because of the words *"One possible processing model"*):
This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="pURI" select="'B.xml'"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <DefaultResult>
            <xsl:if test="doc-available($pURI)">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="doc($pURI)/*"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </DefaultResult>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With any input and `B.xml` been an empty document, Saxon output:

```
<DefaultResult/>
```

And this alternate information:

```
Error on line 1 column 1 of B.xml:
  SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: Premature end of file.
```

Altova Output:

```
<DefaultResult>
    <Entry type="Folder">
        <Name/>
        <Date/>
        <Info>
            <URI>B.xml</URI>
            <Comment/>
            <Files>0</Files>
            <CompressedSize>0</CompressedSize>
            <UncompressedSize>0</UncompressedSize>
            <Ratio>0</Ratio>
            <ContainsEncryptedFiles>false</ContainsEncryptedFiles>
        </Info>
    </Entry>
</DefaultResult>
```

Answer (score -1):

One way is to check whether the root node exists in XSL  and if not print something out.

But when i tried tsimiliar thin in Perl the script hung.So i think you have to check size and then apply the XSL

Answer (score -1):

If your root tag is an empty node set something should work like this...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:choose> 
      <xsl:when test='*[not(*)]'> 
        Empty
      </xsl:when> 
      <xsl:otherwise> 
        Full 
      </xsl:otherwise> 
    </xsl:choose> 
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... If the file is empty (or at least doesn't contain a root element) your XSLT processor will most likely throw and exception.