# Is there an easy way to use XSLT to detect and correct not well-formed XML?

Tags: xml, xslt

For example:

```
<doc xmlns="http://www.foo.org">
  <div id>
    <title>Mr. Title</title>
    <paragraph>This is one paragraph.</paragraph>
  </div>
</doc>
```

Note that the div tag has an attribute id with no value assigned.  I would like to correct it with XSLT, but when I apply the XSL to this XML, it errors "XML Parsing Error: not well-formed" before processing.  Anyone know a way around this?

Thanks!

Comment: Because what you have isn't xml unless it is well formed :P

Comment: Good question, +1. depending on the concrete implementation of a specific XSLT processor, there may exist a very easy and straightforward way for an XSLT transformation to determin whether or not a given resource, identified by a specific URI, is a wellformed XML document. See my answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check XML has a node or it is an empty file using XSLT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018334/how-to-check-xml-has-a-node-or-it-is-an-empty-file-using-xslt) or [Empty XML split out default XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420762/empty-xml-split-out-default-xml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers saying that a prerequisite for the start of the XSLT transformation is to have a well-formed (and parsed) XML document, are correct.

**However**:

1. In XSLT 2.0 having a source XML document is not required.
2. Both XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0 leave to the implementation what to do in case the [**`document()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#function-document) function cannot parse the file identified by the URI (constructed from the) argument. If your XSLT processor does not raise an error and just retutns an empty node-set, **this can be used as a technique to determine if a file identified by a particular URI is well-formed XML document** or not.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is not possible. Even though the result of XSL application does not have to be well formed, the input to it must be.

Comment: To expand, XSL expects an **XML** input (xml implies well-formedness) to be transformed into whatever output.

Comment: @Ignacio-Vazquez-Abrams: You might be interested to know that, depending on the concrete implementation of a specific XSLT processor, there may exist a very easy and straightforward way for an XSLT transformation to determin whether or not a given resource, identified by a specific URI, is a wellformed XML document. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

No. The XML must be parsed before XSLT can be applied to it.

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 2.0, you can use the `doc-available()` function, which returns false if no resource with the given URI exists or if the resource exists but is not XML. If you know what kind of repair work is needed you could then attempt it by reading the resource using the `unparsed-text()` function and manipulating the result as text. In general, though, if someone is sending you bad XML then the recommended approach is to persuade them to stop doing it.