# Omitting a number in XSLT

Tags: xml, regex, xslt

part of my xml i have file is:

```
<Global>
<GlobalParam name="RollName" value="Scene" 10:00:00:00" />
<GlobalParam name="TapeOrg" value="10:00:00:00" />
<GlobalParam name="ReadStart" value="00:00:00:00" />
<GlobalParam name="ReadDuration" value="00:02:05:09" />
</Global>
```

currently my XSL doesn't handle anything in that field and is as follows:

```
 <xsl:template match="GlobalParam">
    <GlobalParam>
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="value">
            <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </GlobalParam>
</xsl:template>
```

this would be normally fine but, the sofware that outputs this if it reprocesses the file it(as you can see above adds the 10:00:00:00 to the file name and the XML file , I need to remove both but i can handle the output filename when i do the translation .

What i need is to remove the `10:00:00:00"` from the roll name field but keep the name intact
 however i was looking at the XSLT schema and i can't find an appropriate function to handle this. Not that experienced with XSLT , i can remove the field alltogether but , well that doesn't help me.

Is there a way to do this possibly by excluding the number if it finds it or , by the space between the name and the time section?.

Any insight would be great

Thanks.

Comment: Provided XML isn't well-formed: `<GlobalParam name="RollName" value="Scene" 10:00:00:00" />`.

Comment: Are you limited to XSLT 1 or can you use XSLT 2?

Comment: As @polishchuk said, your XML not well-formed, so XSLT is not a good answer.  Best answer: Stop the software from adding this data to your XML.  If that's not possible, use something else, some external program, to delete this data.

Comment: A more ideal solution, if possible, is to tell whoever's in charge of the sofware that outputs the above "XML" that the output is broken and needs to be fixed. Presumably that software is supposed to output (well-formed) XML, but it isn't doing so. Unless there's a typo in what you posted in your question.

Comment: No , I am afraid that is the right output . I have complained its not well formed xml but I simply can't change the software/minds. So i am left either doing it through transformation (as i am already doing that ) or with c# i guess.

Comment: Please indicate the XSLT version your software supports.

Comment: +1 for question even if hardly readable.

Comment: Your data isn't XML so why are you asking for help on an XML forum? Your whole mindset is wrong: if you've got a non-XML file, you need non-XML tools to deal with it, so forget things like XSLT that were designed for processing XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need apply pre-processing for input file. If you are using .NET you can use this code to remove `10:00:00:00"`.

```
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?s)(?<!=""\s*)10:00:00:00""", string.Empty);
```

Regex `(?s)(?<!="\s*)10:00:00:00"` will find all `10:00:00:00"` which doesn't have `="` in prefix.

Comment: Yes I was able to use this effectively, and integrate it with with program.

Answer (score 3):

As written in comments your input text is not well formed XML document and probably should be fixed by your provider. For temporary fix you could use some external tool e.g. sed instead of XSLT. I am not telling that you can't use it (check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736657/is-there-an-easy-way-to-use-xslt-to-detect-and-correct-not-well-formed-xml/5736913#5736913) for more), but IMHO this not adequate job for XSLT.

```
sed 's/ 10:00:00:00"//' input.xml
```

Result:

```
<Global>
    <GlobalParam name="RollName" value="Scene" />
    <GlobalParam name="TapeOrg" value="10:00:00:00" />
    <GlobalParam name="ReadStart" value="00:00:00:00" />
    <GlobalParam name="ReadDuration" value="00:02:05:09" />
</Global>
```

**EDIT:**

Here is XSLT 2.0 based solution (tested on [Saxon-HE 9.3](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/)):

**stylesheet.xsl:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:variable name="input" select="unparsed-text('input.xml')"/>

    <xsl:template name="main">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="$input" regex=' 10:00:00:00"'>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**input.xml (not well-formed):**

```
<Global>
<GlobalParam name="RollName" value="Scene" 10:00:00:00" />
<GlobalParam name="TapeOrg" value="10:00:00:00" />
<GlobalParam name="ReadStart" value="00:00:00:00" />
<GlobalParam name="ReadDuration" value="00:02:05:09" />
</Global>
```

**CLI:**

```
java -jar saxon9he.jar -it:main -xsl:stylesheet.xsl -o:output.xml
```

**Result (output.xml):**

```
<Global>
<GlobalParam name="RollName" value="Scene" />
<GlobalParam name="TapeOrg" value="10:00:00:00" />
<GlobalParam name="ReadStart" value="00:00:00:00" />
<GlobalParam name="ReadDuration" value="00:02:05:09" />
</Global>
```

Comment: Yes it really should be fixed by the provider but I am afraid its not possible at the moment. I know its not well formed its just I am getting the output I need using XSLT and wondered if there was/is a way to achieve this using it.

Comment: @user685590: Do you have XSLT 2.0 enabled processor (e.g. Saxon, AltovaXML) ? I am asking that because generally in 2.0 you can use non-XML input for transformation.

Comment: @user685590: As you see it's not best way (but not impossible) with little cheating from my side (one can say that XML **is** de facto text file) and that's why I prefer non-XML tools like sed.

Comment: Afraid I do not have XSLT 2.0. Thank you for going out of your way to provide a solution to a uncommon and slightly backward problem!.